# YouTube App streams much slower than YouTube mobile site on iPhone

Tags: iphone, youtube

I noticed recently that the YouTube app for the iPhone (4s) streams movies significantly slower (or sometimes, not at all) compared to using Safari and the mobile YouTube website.

I have tested this using 3g and various Wi-Fi connections. There is inconsistencies between the App and the Mobile Website on the same device over the same connection.

What is the difference in technologies between these two interfaces that may be causing this, or is this just a localized problem to my device?

Comment: Did you already close all application on your iPhone before wathc youtube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing is happening to mine but looking at the difference in video quality the YouTube app videos are a lot better so that could be why..