# Is there a way to force the youtube app to load videos in non-HD resolutions?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube

When watching youtube on my iPhone 4 I've noticed that by default the videos in the youtube app load at "HD" quality levels.  As my ISP throttles YouTube traffic, this makes watching them impossible.

This question: [YouTube App streams much slower than YouTube mobile site on iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/youtube-app-streams-much-slower-than-youtube-mobile-site-on-iphone) shows how to work around this with mobile Safari, but I'm looking for a way to continue to use the YouTube app.

Is there a way to choose video quality while using the iPhone YouTube app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set this without jailbreaking.
If you do have your iPhone jailbroken you can buy 3G Unrestrictor whose purpose actually is to enable the use of apps that demand to be on WiFi. But one of its features is to force the Youtube quality to your preferred setting.

Comment: At least there's a workaround.